# Соединение не видит драйвер - что делать?

Tags: oracle, java

У меня в третей строчке иксепшин. Мой Connection conn не хочет видеть драйвер. Сижу плачу. Вот:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");String url = "jdbc:ojdbc14::@localhost:1521/isqlplus";Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user, pass); // ->
```

Пишет:

> `Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:ojdbc14::@localhost:1521/isqlplusat java.sql.DriverMqnager.getConnection<DriverManager.java:602>at java.sql.DriverMqnager.getConnection<DriverManager.java:182>at J3.main<J3.java:17>`

Анастасия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Текст ошибки говорит, что подходящий драйвер не найден. Создаем тестовый класс:

```
import java.sql.Connection;import java.sql.DriverManager;import java.sql.ResultSet;import java.sql.SQLException;import java.sql.Statement;public class SampleTest {    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");        String database = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "username", "password");        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();        ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("...");        while(resultset.next())            System.out.println(resultset.getString("..."));        resultset.close();        statement.close();        connection.close();    }}
```

Компилируем

```
javac SampleTest.java
```

Выполняем

```
java -cp ojdbc14.jar;. SampleTest
```

Обратите внимание на строку `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");` и на опцию `-cp`.

Comment: Спасибо Вам Петрович, что откликнулись. Мне очень приятно.Но, и мой TextPad и cmd.exe упорно не видят строчки         Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(database,"hr","hr"); Дают ексепшн. Я плюнула. Ну её к лешему.Спасибо Вам. Извините за беспокойство.